# Enabling shortcodes for custom fields

Tags: functions, custom-field, shortcode

So, in [this post](http://stanhub.com/execute-shortcodes-inside-custom-fields-using-do_shortcode/) it is explained how to supposedly enable shortcodes for custom fields in Wordpress. (Shortcodes are not enabled for custom fields by default.)

What I dont understand is where to place this code:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'name', true)); ?>
```

I understand I have to paste the name of my custom field into the 'name' parameter, but where do I need to place this line of code?

I suppose in the functions.php of the template? I am unsure where though in that file. I don't want to break anything of my template.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: I really don't understand what you are trying to do. Shortcodes should not be executed inside a custom field. Why do you need to do this. BTW, if you are using `do_shortcode()`, then you are doing it wrong.

Comment: I agree it's a bad design, but within my template this currently is the only solution for a certain problem. I need to be able to use a shortcode inside of a custom field. It must be possible, isn't it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Normally Wordpress does not run shortcode that you put into a custom field.

By default, Custom Fields display whatever value you enter, as plain-text, so if you try entering a shortcode, (in the format [shortcode] VALUE [/shortcode]) you’ll end up displaying the entire text, including the tags.

Add the following in your template file, it can be single.php or page.php:

```
echo apply_filters('the_content', get_post_meta($post->ID,'YOUR_CUSTOM_FIELD_NAME', true));
```

or...

```
$shortcode = get_post_meta($post->ID,'YOUR_CUSTOM_FIELD_NAME',true);
echo do_shortcode($shortcode);
```

Comment: hm, I cant get it to work. I gotta admit I don't have the best understanding of how the wordpress framework works under the hood. I tried both your suggested solutions, but neither worked for me. I tried them in the templates page.php file and in the single.php file. Pasted them in the top within the first php-tag. Maybe my template just can't work with these codes.
Btw.: I'm using the custom field on my blog page where all the blog posts are shown together in a preview format.

Comment: Custom fields doesn't work properly on Preview Format. You should save your work before testing.

Comment: -1 Downvote Don't do shortcode https://kovshenin.com/2013/dont-do_shortcode/

Comment: @BradDalton Kovshenin's argument is that you shouldn't use do_shortcode() when you can use the shortcode's callback function directly, so the advice does not apply to the current question. So I'm downvoting your downvote by upvoting the answer!

Comment: Is there a way to do this without modifying a theme template file eg via a simple plugin?